# applying a function to different sheets in different workbooks in R

Tags: r, for-loop, xlconnect

I am new to R and am currently trying to apply a function to worksheets of the same index in different workbooks using the package XLConnect.

So far I have managed to read in a folder of excel files:

```
filenames <- list.files( "file path here", pattern="\\.xls$", full.names=TRUE)
```

and I have looped through the different files, reading each worksheet of each file

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
    tmp<-loadWorkbook(file.path(filenames[i],sep=""))
    lst<- readWorksheet(tmp, 
            sheet = getSheets(tmp), startRow=5, startCol=1, header=TRUE)}
```

What I think I want to do is to loop through the files in filenames and then take the worksheets with the same index (eg. the 1st worksheet of the all the files, then the 2nd worksheet of all the files etc.) and save these to a new workbook (the first workbook containing all the 1st worksheets, then a second workbook with all the 2nd worksheets etc.), with a new sheet for each original sheet that was taken from the previous files and then use

```
for (sheet in newlst){
    Count<-t(table(sheet$County))}
```

and apply my function to the parameter Count.

Does anyone know how I can do this or offer me any guidance at all? Sorry if it is not clear, please ask and I will try to explain further! Thanks :)

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted an example of your Excel file(s), and exactly what you want as output from your example. Don't post the whole thing, just a example just big enough to show us what you want.

Comment: Do all the excels have the same amount of sheets and they are all correctly sorted ? The sorting that you see when you open the .xls might not match what you get in return. Also, do you want a general solution or a solution that uses XLConnect?

Comment: So I just have a list of excel files for each month in the year that all have exactly the same amount of sheets (about 20 I think) and all the sheets contain data about particular populations of different species, each sheet is in the same place for each of the workbooks. For example I have a file for January which contains a sheet for each species of animal and on the sheet there is some data and I want to take the data in the column called County. I want to create a new workbook for each species that has data from each month.

Comment: So say file1 = Jan and then has sheets 'mouse' 'cat' 'dog' etc...
and then file2 = Feb and has the same sheets 'mouse' 'cat' 'dog' etc...
all the way to December, I want to make new worksheets that would contain the information for 'mouse over the year and then 'cat' over the year. So the output should be a workbook for mouse with worksheets for 'jan' 'feb' 'march' etc... and then another workbook for cat with worksheets for 'jan' 'feb' 'march' etc. and then I can extract the data count and apply a function to that (I already have the function prepared and it works for a single workbook)

Comment: and any solution is fine, just a general one or one that uses xlconnect, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should solve your problem:

```
require(XLConnect)

# Example: workbooks w1.xls - w[n].xls each with sheets S1 - S[m]
filenames = list.files("file path here", pattern = "\\.xls$", full.names = TRUE)

# Read data from all workbooks and all worksheets
data = lapply(filenames, function(f) {
  wb = loadWorkbook(f)
  readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb)) # read all sheets in one go
})

# Assumption for this example: all workbooks contain same number of sheets
nWb = sapply(data, length)
stopifnot(diff(range(nWb)) == 0)
nWb = min(nWb)

for(i in seq(length.out = nWb)) {
  # List of data.frames of all i'th sheets
  dout = lapply(data, "[[", i)
  # Note: write all collected sheets in one go ...
  writeWorksheetToFile(file = paste0("wout", i, ".xls"), data = dout, 
                       sheet = paste0("Sout", seq(length.out = length(data))))
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you! Instead of the excel files being called wout1, wout2 etc. is there a way I can get them called whatever the orginal sheet name was?

Comment: Update: It seems that `readWorksheet` has been discontinued as a function in the `XLConnect` / `xlslx` packages. The replacement is `createSheet`

Comment: @GraceMahoney No, it hasn‘t been discontinued. It still exists and serves a different purpose than createSheet.

Comment: Hmm... I tried running this code and it didn't seem to work until I replaced `readWorksheet` with `createSheet`, but I guess I'm mistaken. My bad! I'll look into it further...

Answer (score 0):

using gdata/xlsx might be for the best. Even though it's the slowest out there, it's one of the more intuitive ones.

This method fails if the excels are sorted differently.

Given there's no real example, here's some food for thought.
Gdata requires perl to be installed.

```
library(gdata)
filenames <- list.files( "file path here", pattern="\\.xls$", full.names=TRUE)
amountOfSheets <- #imput something

#This snippet gets the first sheet out of all the files and combining them
readXlsSheet <- function(whichSheet, files){
 for(i in seq(files)){
    piece <- read.xls(files[i], sheet=whichSheet)
    #rbinding frames should work if the sheets are similar, use merge if not.
    if(i == 1) complete <- piece else complete <- rbind(complete, piece)
  }
  complete
}
#Now looping through all the sheets using the previous method
animals <- lapply(seq(amountOfSheets), readXlsSheet, files=filenames)
#The output is a list where animals[[n]] has the all the nth sheets combined.
```

xlsx might only work on 32bit R, and has it's own fair share of issues.

```
library(xlsx)
filenames <- list.files(pattern="\\.xls$", full.names=TRUE)
amountOfSheets <-  2#imput something

#This snippet gets the first sheet out of all the files and combining them
 readXlsSheet <- function(whichSheet, files){
    for(i in seq(files)){
      piece <- read.xlsx(files[i], sheetIndex=whichSheet)
      #rbinding frames should work if the sheets are similar, use merge if not.
      if(i == 1) complete <- piece else complete <- rbind(complete, piece)
    }
  complete
}
readXlsSheet(1, filenames)
#Now looping through all the sheets using the previous method
animals <- lapply(seq(amountOfSheets), readXlsSheet, files=filenames)
```

Comment: okay thank you, when i get to:

animals <- lapply(seq(amountOfSheets), readXlsSheet, files=filenames)

I get the error:
Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
  perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument

Comment: That's an issue with installing gdata. You need to have perl installed. I'm using [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads)